# Predicting standard errors of forecast

Tags: r, stata, linear-regression, forecasting, standard-error

I'm a newbie to R, coming from the Stata world.  I've just run a linear model (with approx 100 variables, each with 500 data points or so) like so:

```
RegModel.3 <- lm(ordercount~timecount2+timecount4 .... expeditedrop, data=Dataset)
```

Now I want to find the standard error of the forecast, like the `stdf` function in stata, for each of the fitted values.

I've tried the following code:

```
predict(RegModel.3$fitted.values, new, se.fit=TRUE)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

What am I doing wrong?  Also, how do I go about exporting the output using the write.csv command in a manner similar to the way I wrote the coefficients:

```
write.csv(RegModel.3$coefficients, file='results.csv')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A reproducible example taken from `?lm`:

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2,10,20, labels=c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)


pp <- predict(lm.D9, interval="prediction",se.fit=TRUE)
```

(see `?predict.lm` for reference) and

```
write.csv(cbind(pp$fit,stderr=pp$se.fit),file="predintervals.csv")
```

should do it.  (In this case the standard errors are all the same because there is a single categorical predictor and no continuous predictor ...)

PS: Whenever possible it's better to use standard accessors, such as `coef()` to extract the coefficients or `fitted()` to extract fitted values, than reaching inside the object with `$`.  Try `methods(class="lm")` to see what accessors are available.

**edit**: an illustration that the general approach still works with a large problem:

```
set.seed(101)
X <- matrix(runif(101*500),nrow=500)
prednames <- paste0("predictor",1:100)
X2 <- setNames(as.data.frame(X),
               c("response",prednames))
form <- reformulate(paste(prednames,collapse="+"),response="response")
fit1 <- lm(form,data=X2)
pp <- predict(fit1,interval="predict",se.fit=TRUE)
```

Comment: When I use predict(), I get the following error: Error in predict.lm(RegModel.3, interval = "prediction", se.fit = TRUE) : 
  subscript out of bounds     --- do you have any idea why I'm getting it?

Comment: @user1884063 please post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: RegModel.3 is the results of a linear regression -- created by RegModel.3 <- lm(orders~timecount, etc.)  -- in all, using 100 or so variables with 500 or so observations each.

Comment: we know, but if that is the case it should (?) be working.  I've just added an example that shows this approach working for a problem the size of yours.  So as stated above we at *least* need to see `str(RegModel.3)` (which *might* help us diagnose the problem), or, preferably, a reproducible example as requested by @Glen_b (please read the linked answer!)